# Deleting csv file vales from mysql table using single query

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I used this query to load data to mysql table. 
           `LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:\upload.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE ms.no_vas LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

**Upload.csv**
`123`
`456`
`789`
`000`
`111`
`222`
`333`
Now i have another csv file `delete.csv` which contents i want to delete from the `ms.no_vas`table. 
**delete.csv**
`456`
`789`

*Note*: these two files contain over 7 million records.

Is there a way to delete all values on `delete.csv` from the `ms.no_vas`table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload the delete.csv into a temporary database, then delete using a subquery.

Example:

```
DELETE FROM ms.no_vas 
WHERE ms.no_vas.value IN (SELECT value FROM temp_delete_table);
```

Answer (score 1):

delete from ms.no_vas where yournumbe = '456' and yournumbe = '789'
using csv

$handle = fopen($file,"r");

```
//loop through the csv file and delete  into database 
do { 
    if ($data[0]) { 


    mysql_query("DELETE from  ms.no_vas where yournumber =  '$data[])')

        ");
```

}

Comment: Also it is not helping in this question but I found it helpful for deleting records from database using PHP. @user911712